# How to add correctly "track by" to ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs

I have this html

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in ::itemsToShow = extensionItems | orderBy:'distance' " class="entry" ng-class="{'alt-background': $index % 2 == 1}" ng-click="itemDetail(item)">
    ...details...
</ion-item>
```

I can't figure out the correct way to add `track by:item._id` I always get this error:

> Syntax Error: Token 'track' is an unexpected token at column 30 of the expression [itemsToShow = extensionItems track by:_id |...

I tried:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in ::itemsToShow = extensionItems track by:item._id | orderBy:'distance' " class="entry" ng-class="{'alt-background': $index % 2 == 1}" ng-click="itemDetail(item)">

<ion-item ng-repeat="item in ::itemsToShow = extensionItems track by:_id | orderBy:'distance' " class="entry" ng-class="{'alt-background': $index % 2 == 1}" ng-click="itemDetail(item)">

<ion-item ng-repeat="item in ::itemsToShow = extensionItems  | orderBy:'distance' track by:_id" class="entry" ng-class="{'alt-background': $index % 2 == 1}" ng-click="itemDetail(item)">

<ion-item ng-repeat="item in ::itemsToShow track by:_id = extensionItems  | orderBy:'distance' " class="entry" ng-class="{'alt-background': $index % 2 == 1}" ng-click="itemDetail(item)">
```

Also tried using `_id` and `item._id` and I always get the same error (different column of course). How or where should I write the `track by` ?

**Edit**: Angular version 1.4.3

**Edit 2**: The Json data have this structure

```
_id: "000000426"
_rev: "1-5003008fcf25b8f130233b944bb761c9"
someText: "<p class="bodytext ">Something for you.</p>"
name : "You-Shop"
homepage : "http://www.youshop.com"
id: 426
```

Comment: what is the angular version?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I added the version to my post, it is 1.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just miss the fact `track by` must **not** be followed by a colon (`:`)...

Answer (score 0):

```
`track by` MUST be the final statement in a ng-repeat.
```